# seaborn.pairplot() - StopIteration ошибка

Tags: python, seaborn

При вызове seaborn.pairplot() для датасета в Jupiter Notebook

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.pairplot(iris)
```

возникает эта ошибка

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [8], line 2
      1 iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
----> 2 g = sns.pairplot(iris)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py:2144, in pairplot(data, hue, hue_order, palette, vars, x_vars, y_vars, kind, diag_kind, markers, height, aspect, corner, dropna, plot_kws, diag_kws, grid_kws, size)
   2142 diag_kws.setdefault("legend", False)
   2143 if diag_kind == "hist":
-> 2144     grid.map_diag(histplot, **diag_kws)
   2145 elif diag_kind == "kde":
   2146     diag_kws.setdefault("fill", True)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py:1507, in PairGrid.map_diag(self, func, **kwargs)
   1505     plot_kwargs.setdefault("hue_order", self._hue_order)
   1506     plot_kwargs.setdefault("palette", self._orig_palette)
-> 1507     func(x=vector, **plot_kwargs)
   1508     ax.legend_ = None
   1510 self._add_axis_labels()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\seaborn\distributions.py:1418, in histplot(data, x, y, hue, weights, stat, bins, binwidth, binrange, discrete, cumulative, common_bins, common_norm, multiple, element, fill, shrink, kde, kde_kws, line_kws, thresh, pthresh, pmax, cbar, cbar_ax, cbar_kws, palette, hue_order, hue_norm, color, log_scale, legend, ax, **kwargs)
   1416     else:
   1417         method = ax.plot
-> 1418     color = _default_color(method, hue, color, kwargs)
   1420 if not p.has_xy_data:
   1421     return ax

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py:139, in _default_color(method, hue, color, kws)
    134     scout.remove()
    136 elif method.__name__ == "bar":
    137 
    138     # bar() needs masked, not empty data, to generate a patch
--> 139     scout, = method([np.nan], [np.nan], **kws)
    140     color = to_rgb(scout.get_facecolor())
    141     scout.remove()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:1423, in _preprocess_data.<locals>.inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1420 @functools.wraps(func)
   1421 def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1422     if data is None:
-> 1423         return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1425     bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1426     auto_label = (bound.arguments.get(label_namer)
   1427                   or bound.kwargs.get(label_namer))

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:2373, in Axes.bar(self, x, height, width, bottom, align, **kwargs)
   2371 x0 = x
   2372 x = np.asarray(self.convert_xunits(x))
-> 2373 width = self._convert_dx(width, x0, x, self.convert_xunits)
   2374 if xerr is not None:
   2375     xerr = self._convert_dx(xerr, x0, x, self.convert_xunits)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:2182, in Axes._convert_dx(dx, x0, xconv, convert)
   2170 try:
   2171     # attempt to add the width to x0; this works for
   2172     # datetime+timedelta, for instance
   (...)
   2179     # removes the units from unit packages like `pint` that
   2180     # wrap numpy arrays.
   2181     try:
-> 2182         x0 = cbook._safe_first_finite(x0)
   2183     except (TypeError, IndexError, KeyError):
   2184         pass

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py:1749, in _safe_first_finite(obj, skip_nonfinite)
   1746     raise RuntimeError("matplotlib does not "
   1747                        "support generators as input")
   1748 else:
-> 1749     return next(val for val in obj if safe_isfinite(val))

StopIteration:
```

Другие методы seaborn работают без проблем.

Пробовала загружать разные датасеты и через read_csv, и через load_dataset - ничего не меняется.

Аналогичный код приведён в документации pairplot() как рабочий: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html

В результате должен получаться график вроде этого:

[image: График из примера в документации]

Comment: Интересно... у меня этот код работает без проблем.

Comment: @strawdog А питон у вас тоже 3.10?

Comment: Скорее всего ваша версия `matplotlib` и/или `seaborn` не совместима с версией питона 3.10, копайте в эту сторону

Comment: @CrazyElf нет, слава богу, не 3.10 )

Comment: @strawdog А у автора вопроса 3.10, а это часто источник всех проблем )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это баг matplotlib 3.6.1, должно быть исправлено в 3.6.2: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/24127

Вместо смены версии Python можно просто откатиться до 3.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо комментаторам, проблема, действительно, оказалась в версии Python

С версией python 3.7.0 pairplot заработал. C версиями 3.9 и 3.10 не вышло.

Для успешного запуска кода в VS Code необходимо:

1. Скачать версию 3.7.0 ([здесь](https://www.npackd.org/p/org.python.Python64/3.7), например) и установить
2. Перезапустить VS Code
3. Открыть файл с кодом .ipynb и нажать на кнопку в правом верхнем углу с версией языка ("Python 3.9", например)
4. Найти версию 3.7. Если она ещё не появилась, то подождите.
5. Установить seaborn

```
    pip install seaborn
```

6. Запустить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код для проверки версии

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
```

Для успешного запуска на локальном сервере Jupiter Notebook нужно изменить ядро (kernel) по умолчанию или добавить новое. Пока что я этого не делала.

Изменение в файле .jupyter.jupyter_notebook_config строки

```
#c.MultiKernelManager.default_kernel_name = 'python3'
```

на

```
c.MultiKernelManager.default_kernel_name = 'py37'
```

ничего не изменило. Попробую добавить версию по инструкциям [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython).